# Bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I am creating men/woman character using MakeHuman tool and import into the blender tool. I followed the steps given in the below youtube video tutorial to work with blender.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYiAd_08-0k

I can generate the armature. But When I skin the armature into the character I got the following error

```
"bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones".
```

What may be the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this message, the reason was that the model wasn't symmetric (after twiddling with an already applied mirror modifier). In this case you could try to cut off one half and mirror it again. After that the parenting with automatic weights should work.

See also this thread on [BA Bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?130935-Bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me was selecting the object and centering it and the root bone to the origin, and rigging the rest of the object.

What is important is that the very first bone that you place is centered at the object.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this as well;

In my case it turned out to be some rather complicated and overlapping geometry near the center of the model (mandibles and a toothy mouth) that I had to weight paint manually  You can mask which vertices get auto painted if you use the `Weights` -> `Assign Automatic From Bones` with face or vertex selection masking, or you can separate the complicated bits from the main mesh and then auto weight paint the main mesh.

I've also had this happen around the toes on barefoot human models, but haven't gone to the trouble of figuring out what specifically was the problem.