Error when trying to use automatic weight paint
I'm having some trouble with the rig ive put together for this model. When i try to join/parent the mesh and the skeleton it gives an error stating: Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones. Doesn anyone know/have any quick or easy solutions for this? Thanks.


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones
