Getting Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones
Since I wanted to replace the Assetto Corsa driver with other models, I unpacked the rider files in them and deleted the driver models, keeping only the skeletons. But it keeps reporting errors, and I've tried everything before this. This model is reporting the same error when I try to bind a skeleton I made myself. Only the skeleton generated with Mixamo works fine.

Duplicate to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2845/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones
